# sql order by from highest to lowest value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

```
SELECT * FROM highscore ORDER BY score
```

This code always sorts my values for lowest to highest but I want them from the highest to the lowest.

Actually I have two sets of data in my table and I always get:

```
0
235235
```

But I need it to be like this:

```
235235
0
```

I have already tried:

```
SELECT * FROM highscore ORDER BY CAST(score AS int)
```

But that gave me a syntax-error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT)' at line 1"

In my table score is set as `int(100)`.

Does anybody have a solution how I could sort them like that? There will never be negative or non-int values.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to use

```
SELECT * FROM highscore ORDER BY score DESC
```

There also exists

```
SELECT * FROM highscore ORDER BY score ASC
```

, but this is the default behaviour.

Comment: ASC = Ascending, DESC = Descending in case OP didn't realize this.